# Convert string into variable in array automatically

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have a problem when Im trying to convert a string to a variable in an array.

The variables are:

```
const n = 1; const s = -1;
```

The array string:

```
let walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 'n'];
```

I want to convert automatically to this variable array:

```
let walk = [n, s, n, s, n, s, n, s, n, n];
```

I'm trying to split but the array still string not a var:

```
let text = walks.toString().split(',').join('-')
console.log(text)
```

Comment: it's in the const above

Comment: Does this help? ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: example of a variable

Comment: yes, its a const var @lost_in_magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put `s` and `n` into an object.

```js
const variables = {
  n: 1,
  s: -1
};

let walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 'n'];

console.log(
  walk.map(variable => variables[variable])
)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript) for more info on accessing variables via another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval`, but it is usually not recommended.

```js
const n = 1; const s = -1;
let walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 'n'].map(eval);
console.log(walk);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Unimitigated said, `eval()` is not recommended to use.

For more details refer to this link [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

For a better way, without `eval()`. You can try this approach

```
const n = 1; const s = -1;
const array = [];
let walk = ['n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 's', 'n', 'n'].map(value => {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + value + ')')();
});
```

I hope this would be useful.